# Symofny : Multiple occurence of input

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have an Entity 'Person' built like this:

```
firstname : string
lastname : string
address : relation <- related to a Address Entity (OneToMany (one Person to many Address))
```

But a Person can have multiple adresse so in the form that i'm trying to build I would like to have a button "Add" to add a new input and I want to be able to retrieve this data when I handle the form in the controller, is it possible to add this form in the AddPersonType.php ??

I know how to create the input element with Javascript but how do I keep trace of it ? because when I try this :

```
$form->getData();
```

It wont show me the field i've 'manually' added

```
$form->get('the_name_of_the_flied');
```

also wont work..
If you don't have a solution but another way to deal with this I would like to know also

Comment: [This page](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html) of the Symfony documentation should describe exactly what you are looking for. More specifically [this part](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype) goes into how to add logic for creating new related entities inside the form.

Comment: thousand ways to rome, one basic thing is, if you have the same formfield name twice it will get stacked into an array